How to Use GoogleAIGeminiChatGenerator for Haystack with Google's Gemini
I am trying my best to run this tutorial right off the Haystack website using Google Colab:
https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/integrations-google-ai
It works up until I reach this code:
from haystack.utils import Secret
from haystack.dataclasses.chat_message import ChatMessage
from haystack_integrations.components.generators.google_ai import GoogleAIGeminiChatGenerator


gemini_chat = GoogleAIGeminiChatGenerator(model="gemini-pro", api_key=Secret.from_token("<MY_API_KEY>"))

messages = [ChatMessage.from_user("What is the most interesting thing you know?")]
res = gemini_chat.run(messages=messages)
for reply in res["replies"]:
    print(reply.content)

messages += res["replies"] + [ChatMessage.from_user("Tell me more about it")]
res = gemini_chat.run(messages=messages)
for reply in res["replies"]:
    print(reply.content)

I then get this error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-868854587ba9> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 
     13 messages += res["replies"] + [ChatMessage.from_user("Tell me more about it")]
---> 14 res = gemini_chat.run(messages=messages)
     15 for reply in res["replies"]:
     16     print(reply.content)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/generativeai/types/content_types.py in to_blob(blob)
    150                 "Could not recognize the intended type of the `dict`\n" "A content should have "
    151             )
--> 152         raise TypeError(
    153             "Could not create `Blob`, expected `Blob`, `dict` or an `Image` type"
    154             "(`PIL.Image.Image` or `IPython.display.Image`).\n"

TypeError: Could not create `Blob`, expected `Blob`, `dict` or an `Image` type(`PIL.Image.Image` or `IPython.display.Image`).
Got a: <class 'google.ai.generativelanguage_v1beta.types.content.Content'>
Value: parts {
  text: "What is the most interesting thing you know?"
}
role: "user"

Checking where that error takes place we're in the to_blob function of content_types.py. We are clearly not processing a blob, so that is strange.
In any case, I've tried everything I can think of to try to get this to work. I've tried explicitly calling:
messages.append(ChatMessage.from_system(content="Tell me more about it"))

I get the same error. I also tried putting this into a dict in the format Gemini would expect (with 'role' and 'parts') and I get a different error earlier on. It is definitely expecting a ChatMessage object here.
It is strange, but there are like 3 different similar tutorials on the official Haystack site and all of them suffer from this error even though they are slightly different how they try to put it together.
Also, it seems to only have a problem if you use ChatMessage.from_system or if you use ChatMessage() where you explicitly set the role to be the system. Trying assistant throws an error that assistant is valid (even though it was clearly one of the valid options in the ChatRole enum)
So I'm stumped how to get Haystack to work with Gemini for this tutorial.

The easiest way to recreate this error is to try to do the tutorial I linked to in Google Colab and you should get the same error as me. If not, let me know and send me a link to the working Colab.

You may want to consult the official documentation to understand how the model works chat_conversations  Then try implementing any third party system your interested in using.

Hey, Bruce! I am from the Haystack team and this seems like a bug. I'm not able to reproduce it right now because of Google geographical restrictions :-) I created a related issue on GitHub, so that we can take a look: https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack-core-integrations/issues/654

This has finally been solved!

The example code on https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/integrations-google-ai is now working!
I'll try out some of the more complex examples too, but I think we can close this particular question since we've confirmed it was a bug.

Here is a google colab that demonstrates it working (though with a simple fix from me): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zwVm1r5T7jAO7QakBDvVrCbUxs4WLJMv?usp=sharing

And here is the original source I'm pulling it from: https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/integrations-google-ai

This issue turned out to be a bug in Haystack.
Here are the two original tutorials:
https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/integrations-google-ai
https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/googleaigeminigenerator
There are still some bugs in these tutorials. But if you want to see a working version of them you can find fixed versions of all of these in this Google colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zwVm1r5T7jAO7QakBDvVrCbUxs4WLJMv?usp=sharing
